# Whats the difference between RuntimeTypeHandle and Type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

And why would I use one over the other in my code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Caution: This answer appears to be out of date.** It was posted before .NET 4 became available, which apparently introduced some optimizations regarding `Type` and thus rendered the information in this answer obsolete. See [this more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1438443/240733) for details.

According to [this blog post (from 2006) by Vance Morrison](http://blogs.msdn.com/vancem/archive/2006/10/01/779503.aspx), `RuntimeTypeHandle` is a value type (`struct`) that wraps an unmanaged pointer, so `Type.GetTypeHandle(obj).Equals(anotherHandle)` is faster to use for strict "is exactly the same type" comparisons than `obj.GetType().Equals(anotherType)` — the latter creates `System.Type` instances which are, apparently, heavier.

However, it's also less obvious, and definitely falls under the category "micro-optimization" so if you're wondering when you need one over the other, you should probably just use System.Type.

Comment: I think GetType() does not create a new instance.

Answer (score 7):

In .NET 4.0 Beta 1 `RuntimeTypeHandle` just wraps `RuntimeType`. 
It seems all benefits of using it as a cheap `Type` proxy have gone.

#### Evidence for the above claim:

- Microsoft's [Reference Source for the `System.RuntimeTypeHandle` type](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtimehandles.cs) shows that this type is indeed only a wrapper around `System.RuntimeType` these days.
- [Sandro Magi's 2013 blog article "CLR: The Cost of Dynamic Type Tests"](http://higherlogics.blogspot.ch/2013/09/clr-cost-of-dynamic-type-tests.html)
   contains a benchmark and a final note showing that the supposed performance benefits of `RuntimeTypeHandle` are gone in .NET 4.